# Python request closes unexpectedly and does not get response

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am working on writing a simple script to manage my router from my Terminal. I am using a local proxy to catch all the endpoints and then using requests to send them.

I am doing the following to send a post request for a reboot function:

```
def reboot(connection):

    reboot_data = {'operation': 'write'}
    reboot = connection.post(TPLINK_RESTART, headers=headers, data=reboot_data)

    if reboot.json()['success']:
        print("Successfully rebooted repeater.")
    else:
        print(reboot.text)
        sys.exit("Unexpected error.")
```

Unfortunately, this code does not reach the if statement and gives the following error:

```
("Connection broken: ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer')", ConnectionResetError(54, 'Connection reset by peer'))
```

From my proxy I can see that this post request went through, and I see the status code as 200 with the following response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "process": "reboot"
}
```

How can I get the response and avoid this error?

Comment: If you are resetting the hardware, how exactly do you imagine you can stay connected to it while it reboots?

Comment: @tripleee As indicated, I am able to get a response when I snoop the request through proxy.